# how can i use iExpress to have single setup from multiple .msi and .exe?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, iexpress

I have two applications which has its own .msi & .exe .
I need a single .exe/.msi that can install my two application on after the other.

Say MyApp1.msi/setup1.exe
    MyApp2.msi/setup2.exe

These two should be included in one setup called MyAppFull.

How can i achieve this in iExpress, i am allowed only this to use in my company.
To use other tools, licensing is required. I also have an Installshield in my VS 2010 premium but it ask for its licensing.
Can you also suggest some tool to accomplish this?

I am using win forms C# 4.0

Comment: What is this "iExpress" thing?

Comment: @Uwe Keim - I read somewhere that is used to create packages having multiple .msi & .exe. So how can i achieve this?

Comment: @UweKeim http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your two setup files are named differently (eg `setup1.exe` and `setup2.exe`, as in your example), this is fairly straightforward.

Because IExpress can only launch one file (pre- and post-extraction), you'll need a batch file that launches the two in order. The batch file can be quite simple:

```
@echo off
setup1.exe
setup2.exe
```

Build your IExpress package; include both setup files, plus the batch file (eg `setup12.bat`). Set the *Install Program* to: `cmd /c setup12.bat`

Thus both files will be executed in the order specified. You can get fancier (eg having the batch file display some kind of output with `echo` or using VBScript, etc) but this should give you some idea.